# Define the top limit of the step in a range slider for Height

Tags: jquery, html

I'm currently using [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/slider/) range sliders for Height and Weight. It works great except the decimals place option doesn't allow a cap of .12 per step for my Height field.

Is there a way to define a top limit for the step?

Current example code is:

```
$('#heightRange').slider({
    range: "min",
    min: 1,
    max: 9,
    step: 0.01,
    value: 5.5,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        //
    }
});
```

The ideal would be to have something like:

```
$('#heightRange').slider({
    range: "min",
    min: 1,
    max: 9,
    step: 0.01,
    step_max: .12
    value: 5.5,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        //
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i don't understand your needs, your step is not fix at 0.01 ?

Comment: Hi @Jax Teller, no because I would need the limit of the step to be 0.12, not 0.99. Does that clarify at all?

Edit: It would need to be 0.12 as there are 12 inches in a foot. With the default going up to 0.99, that would be presented to the user as 99 inches.